# How to address Flexbox with position elements which might be causing issue?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am facing an issue where the `::before` the content is not aligned with the height of its parent. (attaching screenshot). I think this has to do with flexbox settings, but I am not certain.

Can someone suggest what the issue here? and how this can be fixed? I would like to have overflow scroll for the main content and would to the left and right column to be independent.

```css
/* #CSS */

.flex-container {
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
}

#filter-feeds {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.dp-timeline2 {  
border: 1px solid red;

  padding-left: 6px;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.flex-container .right-col {
  flex: 1 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.dp-timeline2:before {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 4px;
  content: "";
  background: #f3f3f3;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--#HTML-->
<div class="flex-xl-nowrap flex-container row">
  <div id="filter-feeds" class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
    Left column
  </div>
  <div class="dp-timeline2 wait-parent col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
     main content <br />
          main content <br />     main content <br />     main content <br />     main content <br />     main content <br />     main content <br />     main content <br />     main content <br />     main content <br />     main content <br />     main content <br />     main content <br />     main content <br />     main content <br />     main content <br />     main content <br />     main content <br />     main content <br />     main content <br />     main content <br />     main content <br />     main content <br />     main content <br />
  </div>
  <div class="right-col d-none d-lg-block  col-md-3"></div>
  Right col
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a codesandbox please

Comment: where is the screesnhot you mentioned above? what is expected output you want is not clear?

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated the code snippet, please take a look. @AlanP.